# Ionic 3 implementation of cordova-plugin-antitampering

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-antitampering

Has anyone implemented this plugin in their project?
I have implemented the plugin but and called this function:

```
window.cordova.plugins.AntiTampering.verify(
    function (success) {
        console.info(success);
        // {“assets”: {“count”: x}} - where x is the number of assets checked
    },
    function (error) {
        console.error(error);
        // gives you the file on which tampering was detected
    }
);
```

The problem is, the function goes in the success block but the count is 0, which means the plugin doesn’t actually scan any files. I want to know what’s wrong.

Mentioning the steps that I have followed:

Step One: Installation using cmd.
command was:
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-antitampering --variable ENABLE_CORDOVA_CALLBACK=true --save

Step two: Invoke method in app.component.ts using this code:

```
declare var window: any;

constructor(){
    this.checkTampering();
}  

checkTampering(){
    alert(“Inside Check Tampering”);
    try {
        alert("Inside Try: ");
        window.cordova.plugins.AntiTampering.verify(
            function (success) {
                alert(JSON.stringify(success));
                // {“assets”: {“count”: x}} - where x is                 the number of assets checked
            },
            function (error) {
                alert(JSON.stringify(error));
                // gives you the file on which tampering was detected
            }
        );
    } catch (e) {
        alert("Caught some exception when implementing Integrity check: " + JSON.stringify(e));
    }
}
```

Step 3 : Run it on the device using command: ionic cordova run android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, I didn't update this issue as soon as I found the solution. A hundred plus views mean that a lot of you guys faced this issue. Basically, you don't have to run the app directly after applying this plugin.
All you need to do is, build an APK file for Android and then install the APK in your phone.
That's when the success handler returns the object success as something like this :
{ "assets" : { "count" : 135 } }
(135 in my case, the count depends on the number of files you got)
 This was basically my fault that I tried directly running the app instead of first building an APK and then installing it on the test device.

Answer (score 0):

Have you gone ahead and tried the Angular implementation of this?

```
var app = angular.module('myApproximatelySecureApp', ['duddu.antitampering']);

app.run(['$antitampering', function ($antitampering) {
    $antitampering.verify().then(function (success) {
        console.info(success);
    }, function (error) {
        console.error(error);
    });
}]);
```

Give that a try and see what the success result is.

Comment: In ionic 3, where do I add this? in the app.component.ts or app.module.ts? Also, The $antitampering reminds me of Angular JS, and I am working with angular 6 in Ionic 3.  Are you sure this is the part that I need to implement? Because according to the documentation here : "https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-antitampering" , this is quoted : "If you are using AngularJS (eg with Ionic), you can use the angular service $antitampering provided with the plugin;" which suggests Ionic 1.